# Base class don't have default constructor when derived class constructor initialization lists

Tags: c++, constructor, derived-class, initializer-list

I just read [Constructors and initialization of derived classes](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/114-constructors-and-initialization-of-derived-classes/)
And I met a question. Code as followed.
The problem is when I comment the father default constructor. There will be a error.
But the default constructor shouldn't be create automatically by compiler?
Thank you for answer my question.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Father{
public:
    int food;
    Father(){} //  father default constructor 
    Father(int f):food(f){
    }
};
class Child: public Father{
public:
    int beverage;
    Child(int b):beverage(b){
    }
};   
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Child c(10);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A default constructor won't be generated if at least a user-defined constructor exists. And in your case, you have one.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare a non-default constructor, the compiler will not create a default on.

I recommend using the `default` keyword for default constructors, so everyone immediately sees what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You Child ctr calls a Father ctr, it has to. It calls the default unless you tell it to do otherwise. Run the below code, then switch which Child ctr is commented, and you will see.

```
class Father{
public:
    int food;
    Father(){ cout<<"father::default\n";} //  father default constructor
    Father(int f):food(f){
    }
};
class Child: public Father{
public:
    int beverage;
//   Child(int b): beverage(b){}
    Child(int b): Father(45), beverage(b){    }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    Child c(10);
    return 0;
}
```

So, if you want to get id of the default constructor, you need to explicitly calls one of the others from within the initilization lists of child class ctrs.